# Хранение элементов listview в массиве и обработка нажатий (simple_list_item_2)

Tags: java, android

Появилась надобность сделать listview с двумя textview. Знаю, что это делается с simple_list_item_2. У меня достаточно много элементов listview поэтому желательно как-то хранить данные в массиве. И есть несколько textview2. Мне надо как-то узнать надпись textview2 нажатого элемента и запустить соответствующую активность. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Не могу найти об этом информацию

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", "1. one");
    map.put("Sbor", "сборник один");
    arrayList.add(map);

    // Досье на второго кота
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", "2. two");
    map.put("Sbor", "сборник один");
    arrayList.add(map);

    // Досье на третьего кота
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", "3. three");
    map.put("Sbor", "сборник два");
    arrayList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrayList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[]{"Name", "Sbor"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            recreate();
        }
    });
}
```

На всякий случай для удобства. Буду благодарен любой подсказки.

Comment: Хоть это и оффтоп, но для начала я вам рекомендую забыть про ListView и использовать RecyclerView. Потому что ListView уже никто не использует лет 5 наверное

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет. Буду разбираться:)